# Java - HashMap for booking system

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I have been given an exercise to develop an appropriate data structure to implement a tennis court booking system.

A hashmap is what is required for this and I was given a diagram as a visual representation of the data structure.

From looking at the diagram, I am unclear on how the Key and Value should be defined in the HashMap. Should 'Court' be a class, which is the Key?

For the value, it shows a time, and a players name. How would the value be defined, since it has two values of time and player name?

[diagram link](https://ibb.co/3yPxKSF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we have a HashMap named as "Date1".
Well, now i can put a value with a key in this "Date1" HashMap & later can retrieve that value with the key -> `Date1.get("key")`

According to your diagram, the keys will be *court1, court2, ....*

So that, when i will ask for `Date1.get("court1")`, i can get [this ArrayList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMn69.png)

But, in this arraylist, each row consist of two values. If our list had one string values in each row, we could say that this is a arraylist of string type.

So lets make our own class (like a type) which can store two values (like "9:00", "player")

```
public class EntryInfo{
    String time, player;
    
    public EntryInfo(String time, String player) {
        this.time = time;
        this.player = player;
    }
}
```

So if we create an object of "EntryInfo" class, that object will be able to store two values - and each row of our arraylist is of this type.

so, lets sum up :

our hashmap key will be "court1, court2..."
and each key will hold values of `ArrayList<EntryInfo>` type.

So our hashmap will be like `HashMap< String, ArrayList<EntryInfo> >`

---

Now, lets imagine the scenario according to your diagram.

first, lets talk about usage scenario.
Say, there are several courts in your school. They are named as *court1, court2, court3, ...*

well, I want today's entry-log for court1.
So, i will just ask for `feb9.get("court1")`, and it will return a list (ArrayList), and i can traverse that array to see the log like following:

```
for(EntryInfo entryinfo : feb9.get("court1") ) {
    System.out.println(entryinfo.time + " : " + entryinfo.player);
}
```

Yeah, thats it. If i want to get the log for court2, i will retrieve the value using key "court2"

Now, lets discuss how to make this.

well today is feb9, lets make a hashmap to store today's entry log. Lets name the hashmap "feb9"

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<EntryInfo>> feb9 = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<EntryInfo>>();
```

your school has 3 courts. Lets add 3 different keys to this hashmap so that it can hold 3 separate and corresponding entry-logs for each key(court)

```
feb9.put("court1", new ArrayList<EntryInfo>());
feb9.put("court2", new ArrayList<EntryInfo>());
feb9.put("court3", new ArrayList<EntryInfo>());
```

You can relate this with creating 3 new files named court1, court2 & court3. Each file consists of an ArrayList object, which is empty for now.

Say, now at 9:00 am, player "zineryt" enters court1. Lets entry the log into our hashmap

```
feb9.get("court1").add(new EntryInfo("9:00", "zineryt"));
```

Here `feb9.get("court1")` will return an ArrayList, and we used add() method to insert elements into the ArrayList.

say, at 9:50am, player "bigboy" enters court1. We can entry the log like below

```
feb9.get("court1").add(new EntryInfo("9:50", "bigboy"));
```

and it goes like this.

For tomorrow's information, we will create another new HashMap named feb10 and will follow the same steps.

Comment: Thank you!  Think I get this. Just wondering how you add the arrayList to the hashMap. For example for hashmap with key court1, how the arraylist is added when adding a new entry to the hashmap?  Is a new arraylist created for each key?

Comment: i've edited the response and added a scenario for example, please check

Comment: Thanks for that :) That did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Date1 (what a name) is a `Map<String, Court>` of courts by name, like "court1". Court has fields name and a reservation list.

So the key is (probably) a String, and the class itself is the value. One often sees, that the key/ID is also kept in the value class. So a Court object suffices to get its name.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a `HashMap` for each `Date1` is an odd and confusing approach for a `HashMap` can't really represent a date as we understand it. but given that this is the assignment, you have to keep information about the court number, the playtime and the competitors names. These are at least three fields, if we concat the competitors names to one `String`.

With only using `HashMap` you will probably have to use a multi-dimensional `HashMap`.

```
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>> Date1 = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
```

The outer `HashMap` holds the *court number as the key of type* `Integer` and the *pairings as the value of type* `HashMap`.
The inner `HashMap` holds the *playtime as key of type* `String` (though you might as well use the type `Time`) and the c*ompetitors names as value of type* `String`.

When creating this, it is vital to generate addintional accessors to avoid tedious chained calls of `Date1.get(someIntVariable).get(someStringOrTime)` to receive the players names.

```
public HashMap<String, String> getPairingsForCourt(int court) {
    return Date1.get(court);
}

public String getPlayersForCourtOnTime(int court, String time) {
    return getPairingsForCourt(court).get(time);
}
```

By any chance getting familiar with all the aspects of `HashMap` requires some time. Especially if you come across mechanisms like `keySet()` or `entrySet()`. Have a look on here for a detailed yet understandable start:
[A Guide to Java HashMap](https://www.baeldung.com/java-hashmap)